# administrator unable to trash custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been pounding my head against a wall on this one.

WordPress 4.4.1 | Divi 2.4.6.4 (with child theme) | Using Members plugin 1.1.1

I have attempted to change the capabilities_type on a custom post type from the theme I'm using (Divi). I have changed it from the default so I can continue to deny users from editing posts, while giving them permission to edit the custom post type.

The Members plugin manages role permissions. Before I added any code, the only way I could allow users to have access to the custom post type, I would have to give them permission to: Posts, as well as the CPT, which is too much. There is no tab for my CPT (Projects), within the Members plugin at this point.

[image: Members plugin before first block of code]

After I added the initial code (Add Author to Projects change capability_type), a "projects" tab showed up in the Members plugin.

[image: Members plugin after first block of code]

I also added some custom capabilities through the Members plugin, and granted access to the admin.

[I Added custom capabilities (delete_others_submissions, delete_published_submissions, delete_submission, delete_submissions, etc.) to the members plugin for the 'submission(s)' capabilities_type]

At this point, as an administrator, I now only have view and delete capabilities for the CPT.

When I add the rest of the code I am able to edit, and view, but not delete the CPT. I can allow or deny the other users access so I am now most of the way there. But I am unable to delete any of the posts, even as administrator.

my code is:

```
// Add Author to Projects change capability_type

add_filter( 'et_project_posttype_args', 'add_author_on_divi_projects' );
function add_author_on_divi_projects ($args) {
$args['supports'] = array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'author' );
$args['capability_type'] = array( 'submission', 'submissions' );
return $args;
}

// Customize Projects Custom Post Type

add_filter( 'et_project_posttype_args', 'qd_add_submission_caps', 1, 3);
function qd_add_submission_caps($data, $post_type) {
     if($post_type == 'submission'){
         $args = array(
           'capabilities' => array(
               'edit_post' => 'edit_submission',
               'edit_posts' => 'edit_submissions',
               'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_submissions',
               'publish_posts' => 'publish_submissions',
               'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_published_submissions'
        ),
    'map_meta_cap' => true
    );
    $data = array_merge($data, $args);
  }
  return $data;
}

    // Meta cap

    add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'my_map_meta_cap', 10, 4 );

    function my_map_meta_cap( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
            if ( 'edit_submission' == $cap || 'delete_submission' == $cap || 'read_submission' == $cap ) {
            $post = get_post( $args[0] );
            $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
            $caps = array();
}

if ( 'edit_submission' == $cap ) {
    if ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
        $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_posts;
    else
        $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_others_posts;
}
elseif ( 'delete_submission' == $cap ) {
    if ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
        $caps[] = $post_type->cap->delete_posts;
    else
        $caps[] = $post_type->cap->delete_others_posts;
}
elseif ( 'read_submission' == $cap ) {
    if ( 'private' != $post->post_status )
        $caps[] = 'read';
    elseif ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
        $caps[] = 'read';
    else
        $caps[] = $post_type->cap->read_private_posts;
}
return $caps;
}
```

I hope I have given enough info and haven't made it too confusing. I feel like I am so close.